# What is an "L.Mgt" qualification?

Tags: cv, degree

I'm a software engineer in the process of building an information system for a UK university, and one of the staff members' (whose details I have to house in the system) highest qualification level is listed as "L.Mgt".

I've Googled the hell out of the internet and for the life of me I can't figure out what this qualification is. Can someone tell me what this is exactly?

Comment: This question is one example, among many, that clearly shows that people should avoid using abbreviations that are not universally recognized, without first defining them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My own work is on the STEM / hard science side of Academia, so I don't have first-hand knowledge about this qualification, but I would read it as a [Licenciate degree in Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licentiate#United_Kingdom).

A cursory search turns up a few institutions that offer such a degree:

- [University of
  Tampere](http://www.uta.fi/jkk/en/doctoralstudies/index.html)
- [Lund University](http://www.lusem.lu.se/study/phd)
- [Universidad de Navarra](http://www.unav.edu/en/web/facultad-de-ciencias-economicas-y-empresariales/estudios/licenciaturas)
- [Pontifical University of Comillas](http://www.altillo.com/en/universities/spain/Pontifical_University_of_Comillas.asp)
- [Universidade Lusófona](http://www.ulusofona.pt/en/schools/scaait/degrees-1st-cycle/degree-in-management-information-technology.html)

Comment: I'm going to track down the staff member in question this week, and confirm then whether this is what he has in mind.

Comment: Spot on - the fella in question is Portuguese, and this sort of qualification is apparently equivalent to a UK Bachelor of Science with Honours. Excellent work sir.